# Stored Procedure in mysql showing error in Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am creating stored procedure in MySQL workbench.
Although code looks fine but there shows some error which I couldnot figure out.Pl help.

```
create procedure UpdateAge(in employeeId int, in age int)
begin
    update abc.employeedata set EmployeeAge= age where EmployeeId= employeeId ;
end
```

Error is: extraneous input found. expected end of input

Comment: abc is database name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's just one statement, you probably don't need `begin` and `end`. Try

```
create procedure UpdateAge(in employeeId int, in age int)
update abc.employeedata set EmployeeAge= age where EmployeeId= employeeId ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create procedure UpdateAge(in employeeId int, in age int)
begin
    update abc.employeedata set EmployeeAge= age where EmployeeId= employeeId ;
end ;
```

Add semicolon to the end statement also

Comment: Remove the extra space near the semicolon and try

Comment: that too of no use. :/